# Parse table with BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

If I want to read entries in a table which follows the format:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">

stuff

</table>
```

I'm using this as my current method:

```
pg = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
page = BeautifulSoup(pg)
table = page.find('table', cellpadding = 4, cellspacing = 0)
```

My `table` can't read the tag properly, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Your code works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested this with both BeautifulSoup versions 3 and 4. Your code works with BS4, so you must be using version 3.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS4 # Version 4
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as BS3 # Version 3
>>> bs3soup = BS3("""<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
... 
... stuff
... 
... </table>""")
>>> bs4soup = BS4("""<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
... 
... stuff
... 
... </table>""")
>>> bs3soup.find('table', cellpadding = 4, cellspacing = 0) # None
>>> bs4soup.find('table', cellpadding = 4, cellspacing = 0)
<table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">

stuff

</table>
```

So, if you want to continue with BS3, this should fix it:

```
>>> soup.find('table', cellpaddin="4", cellspacing="0") # Notice how the integers are now strings, like in the HTML.
```

However, you should be using version 4 (`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`).