# beautifulsoup parsing table with no id or class attributes in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use beautifulsoup to parse the data in the table in the url below,

http://hk.warrants.com/home/en/sgdata/list_e.cgi#topsearch

Since the table has no class attributes or id, I cannot use the normal approach of soup.find( "table", {"title":"TheTitle"} ) to locate the table. Instead, I have tried,

```
warrantUrl = 'http://hk.warrants.com/home/en/sgdata/list_e.cgi#topsearch'
warrantPage = urlopen(warrantUrl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(warrantPage, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find_all("tr")
paragraphs = []
for x in table:
    paragraphs.append(str(x))
```

Also, I tried the method mentioned in this post,
[Parse table with BeautifulSoup Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333026/parse-table-with-beautifulsoup-python) . But no success...

Answer (score 0):

The site uses javascript, BeautifulSoup can't turn it to html, it can't process it, neither can urllib, you need to check out Ghost for python.

http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/

Read the documentation, it's really easy, powerful and similar to requests. It has the ability to "evaluate" javascripts and return their values in various ways.

Comment: Check it out, and if you need any help don't hesitate to ask